# Using f-strings to format a 6-digit number with commas, round it to 1 significant figure and avoid scientific notation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

This is my code so far:

```py
number = 201234
print(f'number is {number:,.0f}')
```

This prints: **number is 201,234**

However I want it to print: **number is 200,000**

I've tried using `print(f'number is {number:,.1g}')` but this prints in scientific notation like so: **number is 2e+05**

Is there a simple way to format this to get the desired outcome?

Comment: Why not just `f'{str(number)[0]}00,000'`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `round()` function with a negative argument.

```
number = 201234
print(f'number is {round(number, -5):,.0f}')
```

Prints

```
number is 200,000
```

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked duplicate already covers this. Please don't answer duplicate questions. Instead, flag this one / vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, I wanted to know if it's possible to do this with f-strings and without using round.